# How to switch a div content that has php values

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have two php variables. I want to create a read more button to toggle these two values, one is the excerpt, the other is the full content. I am very new to php and jQuery. Have spent few hours trying to figure it out :( I really appreciated if someone can help...

I tried to change id and class to achieve my goal. I believe this might be really stupid. But I really don't know the smart way.

Can somebody give me some direction please? Right now, the Alert I put in the codes returns "undefinied"...

**PHP :**

```
$trimmed = '<p id="short_desc" class="show_desc">' . chinese_excerpt( get_the_content(), $lenth  = 260 ) . '</p>';
            $full    = '<p id="full_desc" class="hide_desc">' . get_the_content() . '</p>';

            echo apply_filters( 'the_resume_description', $trimmed );
            echo apply_filters( 'the_resume_description', $full );

            echo '<div style="float:right; margin-top:-30px"><div id="show_more">Read More...</div></div>'
```

**HTML :**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready( function () {

            $( "#show_more" ).click( function ( ) {
                if ( $( '#short_desc' ).attr( 'id' ) === "short_desc" ) {
                        $( "#short_desc" ).removeClass("show_desc");
                            $( "#short_desc" ).addClass("hide_desc");
                            $( "#short_desc" ).attr( 'id',$( "#full_desc" ) );  
                            $( "#full_desc" ).removeClass("hide_desc");
                            $( "#full_desc" ).addClass("show_desc");
                    } else if ( $( '#full_desc' ).attr( 'id' ) === "full_desc" ){                               
                            $( "#full_desc" ).removeClass("show_desc");
                            $( "#full_desc" ).addClass("hide_desc");
                            $( "#full_desc" ).attr( 'id',"#short_desc" );
                            alert($( '#short_desc' ).attr( 'id' ));
                            $( "#short_desc" ).removeClass("hide_desc");
                            $( "#short_desc" ).addClass("show_desc");
                                };
                    } );
} );
                                    </script>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your alert is undefined because the ID was undefined when you assigned it in `$( "#short_desc" ).attr( 'id',$( "#full_desc" ) );`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this : [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/L0j5x8ow/3/)

```js
$( ".show_hide" ).click(function() {   
    if ($('.hide_desc').css('display') == 'none') {
        $(".hide_desc").show();
    $(".show_desc").hide();
    $(this).html('Read More');
    }else{
         $(".hide_desc").hide();
    $(".show_desc").show();
    $(this).html('Read Less');
    }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="show_desc" style="display:none">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet nisl vitae porttitor elementum. Aliquam lobortis, augue in molestie convallis, metus nibh euismod sapien, vitae egestas nisl nunc eu diam. Ut elit elit, fringilla eu ultricies vel, pulvinar a metus. Sed quis urna feugiat, lacinia metus eget, sodales dui. Suspendisse potenti. Duis in turpis quis tellus vulputate ornare. Fusce adipiscing tellus diam, ut pellentesque tortor rhoncus sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet nisl vitae porttitor elementum. Aliquam lobortis, augue in molestie convallis, metus nibh euismod sapien, vitae egestas nisl nunc eu diam. Ut elit elit, fringilla eu ultricies vel, pulvinar a metus. Sed quis urna feugiat, lacinia metus eget, sodales dui. Suspendisse potenti. Duis in turpis quis tellus vulputate ornare. Fusce adipiscing tellus diam, ut pellentesque tortor rhoncus sit amet.</p>
        <p class="hide_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet nisl vitae porttitor elementum. Aliquam lobortis, augue in molestie convallis, metus nibh euismod sapien, vitae egestas nisl nunc eu diam. Ut elit elit, fringilla eu ultricies vel, pulvinar a metus. Sed quis urna feugiat, lacinia metus eget, sodales dui. Suspendisse potenti. Duis in turpis quis tellus vulputate ornare. Fusce adipiscing tellus diam, ut pellentesque tortor rhoncus sit amet.</p>
       
    <div style="float:right;"><div class="show_hide">Read More...</div></div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your quick response! Your code works great! It's working perfectly now! I really appreciated! You are the pro! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code was almost there!

You should likely leave the ID's alone and just add and remove your required classes.

Also, if you really did want to change the id, it's a textual field so you would just change it using `$( "#short_desc" ).attr( 'id',"full_desc");` rather than `$( "#short_desc" ).attr( 'id',$( "#full_desc" ) );`

Lastly, a check of a thing against itself like short_desc id against it's id in `$( '#short_desc' ).attr( 'id' ) === "short_desc"` should always return true. If something always returns true you can exclude the check. 
I'm going to assume you wanted a "read more" / "read less" kind of thing instead.

Here's a working version:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#show_more").click(function () {
        console.log("clicked");
        if ($('#short_desc').hasClass("show_desc")) {
            $("#short_desc").removeClass("show_desc");
            $("#short_desc").addClass("hide_desc");
            $("#full_desc").removeClass("hide_desc");
            $("#full_desc").addClass("show_desc");
            $("#show_more").text("Read Less...");
        } else {
            $("#full_desc").removeClass("show_desc");
            $("#full_desc").addClass("hide_desc");
            console.log($('#short_desc').attr('id'));
            $("#short_desc").removeClass("hide_desc");
            $("#short_desc").addClass("show_desc");
            $("#show_more").text("Read More...");
        }
    });
});
```

And a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb6xsvho/) to play with it in.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your explanation.  Although by the time I see your reply, I actually already just solved it with the first answer. I do really appreciated you taught me some essential knowledge :)  I don't know which one to vote. Both are great. Thank you for your time! You guys rock!